# Windows network access and security log

Tags: windows, networking

I need some help on something... today I figured out that my Visual Studio was uninstalled from my pc.... this is a corporative computer, and I have reasons to thing that one of the guys of networking uninstalled it using some kind of network organization tool or something like that, that kind of things in corporations that they install and uninstall things in the background of your computer... after take a look to my event viewer, it seems VS was uninstalled about a week ago at 11:42 pm saying "Windows installer removed the product VS" blabla, I know I dont remove that, so must be some kind of background operation.... Is there any way to check if my software was removed for someone else? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There is the event viewer message includes User field. This says you who do that.